# Extension of averaged nonexpansiveness for mappings that are not self maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. We say that an operator $f:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is

- Nonexpansive if $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_{\mathcal{H}} \le \|x - y\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ holds for every $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$.
- $\alpha$-averaged if it can be written as $(1-\alpha)\text{Id} +\alpha g$, where $g:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is nonexpansive and $\text{id}:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is the identity operator.

Remarkably, averaged operators behave well under composition and convex combination. Also, the iteration of an averaged operator is known to converge weakly to a fixed point under the assumption that such a point exists.

Can we extend this definition for mappings that are not necessarily self maps while preserving the essence of its properties? That is, can we define $\alpha$-averaged mappings of the form $f:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is another Hilbert space?

Comment: If you consider the cardinality of the orthonormal basis $B_1$ of range(f) and the orthonormal basis $B_2$ of $H$, then card(B_1)\leq card(B_2). In this sense, you can view range(f) as a closed linear subspace of $H$, which reduced to the self-map case.